# How does a UILabel/UIbutton etc works even after releasing them from memory?

Tags: iphone, uikit

For example:

```
        UILabel *lblEmail = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 10, 70, 30)];
[lblEmail setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
[lblEmail setText:@"Email"];
[lblEmail setTag:1];
[contentView addSubview:lblEmail];
[lblEmail release];
```

In the above code, we create one UILabel and release it and hence has no memory reference anymore, but still it's works while I am running the application. and we can change it's value using viewWithTag also. Other example would be I create one button and release it but still in the when user clicks on the buttons it works.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Content view retained the label / button, so it is still around. You create it with a retain count of 1, adding it to the contentView gives it a retain count of 2, and releasing it gives it a retain count of 1. So it is still around.

Answer (score 3):

It's not released from memory. You are just releasing *your* retention of it. When you add it as a subview of `contentView` it is retained internally there.

Comment: Yes I am aware of this... but let's take a case of Registration form where my content view has 10 labels & 10 textfield... then my contentView retain count is 21... how can I manage such situation?

Comment: you manage this by following a simple rule... if you are responsible for creating (alloc/init, copy, etc) or retaining an object, you are responsible for releasing.

Comment: Your contentView retain count is NOT 21. If you add 10 labels and 10 textFields, EACH label and text field has a retain count of 1 and the contentView itself has a retain count of 1 (assuming nothing else in the application has a hold on these objects).

Comment: Right, and as a side note: Do NOT worry about the retain count at any given point, just be responsible for your actions that increased it and release as needed. Too many people look at retainCount and try to make sense of it.

Answer (score 0):

Apple Docs states [- (void)addSubview:(UIView *)view](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html) retains *view* and sets the view’s next responder to the receiver, which is its new superview.

Answer (score 0):

lblEmail will only be deallocated once it's reference count is 0. It is retained by contentView.

Answer (score 0):

Read the Apple Documentation for `addSubview`.

```
- (void)addSubview:(UIView *)view
```

**The view to be added. This view is retained by the receiver**

[Apple Documentation for UIView](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html)